# Online Dictionary for Scraping

Tags: language, web-crawling, english, dictionary

Does anybody know if there is an extensive online dictionary other than Wiktionary that lists many words on a single page, as opposed to having to search for a single word?

None of the online dictionaries that I am aware of actually display lists of words for some reason.

Comment: Do you need just the words (http://wordlist.aspell.net/), or words with definitions (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8233/largest-open-source-dictionary-w-brief-definitions-not-wiktionary)

Comment: @BarryCarter all i need are the words. ill check those out.

Comment: @BarryCarter however, definitions would be necessary if the words cant be found elsewhere in other dictionaries

Answer (score 1):

You can use data from Wiktionary.

Wikimedia provides data dumps for all its websites [here](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html) (ctrl+f "wiktionary"), that way you don't have to scrape.

Although the dumps seem to be regular, if you want to scrape the latest version, then there's a page on that: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Parsing.

Comment: interesting. i was hoping for a dictionary other than wiktionary. wiktionary contains a lot of words that arent contained in other dictionaries unfortunately

Comment: Check out the link to english.SE question in a comment by Barry on your question. It contains non-wiktionary sources

Comment: yah i have briefly looked at it. i found a solution for myself already tho

Comment: @BugWhisperer If you found a solution please post it as an answer. It's a good way to give back to the community that volunteered their time to help you.

Comment: @csk i know. im an avid user of stackoverflow. still would appreciate more answers, preferrably not wiktionary since it includes a lot of words that cannot be found in other dictionaries.

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha done and did

Answer (score 1):

i found a website with 10,000 words that I'm using for my project. mabey this will work?
[https://www.mit.edu/~ecprice/wordlist.10000](https://www.mit.edu/%7Eecprice/wordlist.10000)

Comment: thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

Here are all of the terms in the Cambridge dictionary broken down into lists.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/browse/english/